# Connect PC C++ with android tablet via wifi direct

Tags: c++, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Can I establish socket connection via wifi direct with PC using something like (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769062(v=vs.85).aspx) 
and 
android tablet 
using this (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)?

Does anybody have such experience?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Since each of Android, Windows and modern desktop operating systems (Linux, OS X, etc.) have an implementation of the C standard library (to some extent, at least), you can use [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) to establish a TCP connection from one device to the other.

Comment: Using wifi direct precisely? The question was about that, not about sockets in general. I need peer to peer connection using wifi and service discovery is desirable.

Comment: @SergeyLapin Then you implement service discovery after having made sure both devices connect to the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Thank you! Hope I can make this thing tomorrow)

Comment: This answer does not answer the question nor add any information to it.